# Unity: Fps drops after a while

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I am building an Unity application as a visual stimulation for a neuroscience study. Basically, my application just shows several flickering planes periodically. However, I noticed that every time after I ran the application for a few minutes, the fps dropped to around 10~30 shown in the profiler. The drop of fps happened in both editor mode or build. Since my script is totally in cycle, I am guessing there were some accumulative issues like GC or memory leak?

Also, I noticed that when the fps starts to become unstable, I can click the Pause button in the tool bar of the Editor and then resume the application, the fps will become stable for a further period. Therefore, I am wondering what actually happens when the Pause button is clicked? Does pressing the Pause button clear or reset anything so the fps can go back to full?

Comment: well your description is really vague and it is really hard to pinpoint the problem. Do you mind sharing some code, or actually explaining what your script does? Do you move gameobjects around, do you work with meshes ... etc? An elevated number ob gameobjects moving could cause a frame drop, a lot of instantiate at the same time, particle systems...
if you are using physics you should use a FixedUpdate and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a similar problem, it helped just turning off "Record" in the Unity profiler. Recording consumes so much memory and the fps drop, especially when there are a lot of function calls (like deep recursions). 
It doesn't sound like you are constantly creating new GameObjects and not deleting the old ones, but that would be the 2nd thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you use lot of drag-drop references or in short form [SerializeFields], you will lose performance resulting reduced FPS. Try to get everything you want in Awake, specially MonoBehaviours, this worked for me to increase FPS. By everything I didn't mean you have to keep things hard coded everywhere. Just the classes and other things like gameObjects. Floats, int, bools,strings, lists<> should be okay and better to be serialized.